# How do I access Windows 8 Recovery partition and how to recover it to factory image?

Tags: windows, windows-8, system-recovery

On Windows 7 I usually enter into Windows Recovery partition by using F7 and choosing it to recovery mode. Now on Windows 8 F7, F8 or any of FXX keys works on booting (even on Full Reboot).

**How do I access Windows 8 boot options or Windows 8 Recovery and how I should proceed to recovery my Windows 8 into factory image (when present)?**

Comment: F7 and a recovery partition would be setup by the OEM.  If you blew away/changed/upgraded your OEM Windows install, F7 probably isn't going to work anymore. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows 8 they dropped the use of the F8 key to access the boot menu.

Now to access such menu you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> before you press Restart (so already within Windows) and you'll be presented with it after the reboot. Another way is to press "Restart now" at the general PC settings:

[image: General PC settings]

As usual, Windows automatically shows the menu when it detects an error and can't continue booting anyway.

Boot menu:

[image: Boot menu]

Troubleshoot:

[image: Troubleshoot menu]

Advanced options:

[image: Advanced options menu]

You can find more information about it in a [TechSpot article](https://www.techspot.com/news/48718-windows-8-removes-need-for-f8-key-advanced-boot-menu-redesigned.html) or [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/designing-for-pcs-that-boot-faster-than-ever-before) at MSDN.

To proceed with a recovery process once there go to the troubleshoot menu and select to either refresh or reset the machine. You can find some more information about the process in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495907/how-to-refresh-or-reset-windows-8-without-the-system-reserved-partition/495936#495936) other question's answer.

Comment: If Windows won't boot, then it should detect the issue, and restart into the repair partition automatically.